# what does a question mark ? represent in asql query

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

```
SELECT i.instype = 'BuySellBack' ?
       i.exp_day = m.Reportdate ? x(t) * (-1) :
       x(t,m.ReportDate)  :  x(t,m.ReportDate)
FROM i
```

Comment: I don't know about your SQL vendor but this looks like a ternary condition (there'd be 2 of them, nested): `condition ? if-true : if-false`. If those are ternary conditions, they could probably be rewritten to something like `i.instype = 'BuySellBack' AND i.exp_day = m.Reportdate ? x(t) * (-1) : x(t,m.ReportDate)` to avoid nesting them (*"else"* parts are the same).

Comment: https://www.educba.com/ternary-operator-in-sql/  adds some explanations but I can't find any other documentation on this syntax.  I'm use to using nested if, case expressions etc. or more:  https://www.webcodeexpert.com/2017/09/sql-statement-equivalent-to.html

Comment: Both Teradata database and SQL assistant recognize ? as a "parameter marker". In SQL it's generally better to use standard CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END syntax instead.